# Create new datetime value based on 2 values on pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with the bellow types:

```
Case_Key                     int64
Activity                    object
Timestamp           datetime64[ns]
Vendor                      object
Plant                       object
Country                     object
City                        object
Net_Order_Value            float64
Order_Queantity            float64
Time_Difference    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

And this structure:

```
    Case_Key    Timestamp   Time_Difference
0   1000    2016-01-01 08:35:07 0 days
5   1000    2016-01-20 08:35:07 8 days
6   1000    2016-01-26 08:35:07 6 days
7   1000    2016-02-09 08:35:07 14 days
8   10000   2016-01-26 11:57:47 0 days
11  10000   2016-02-05 11:57:47 7 days
12  10000   2016-02-11 11:57:47 6 days
13  10000   2016-02-26 11:57:47 15 days
14  100000  2016-10-13 10:00:01 0 days
17  100000  2016-10-26 10:00:01 9 days
```

An example of what i want to achieve: Take the first timestamp (2016-01-01) add the Time_Difference from the second row (8 days) and replace the Timestamp of the second row to (2016-01-09). Then do the same for the next rows grouped by the Case_Key column ,take the previous timestamp (2016-01-09) and add 6 days with the desired outcome to be (2016-01-15).

Desired outcome:

```
0   1000    2016-01-01 08:35:07 0 days
5   1000    2016-01-**09** 08:35:07 8 days
6   1000    2016-01-**15** 08:35:07 6 days
7   1000    2016-02-**29** 08:35:07 14 days
```

And this is desired to be done for each row grouped by the same Case_Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for repeat first value per groups of column `Timestamp` and then use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) by cumulative sums of timedeltas by cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
s = df.groupby('Case_Key')['Time_Difference'].apply(pd.Series.cumsum)
#because failed with timedeltas
#s = df.groupby('Case_Key')['Time_Difference'].cumsum()
df['Timestamp'] = df.groupby('Case_Key')['Timestamp'].transform('first').add(s)
print (df)
    Case_Key           Timestamp Time_Difference
0       1000 2016-01-01 08:35:07          0 days
5       1000 2016-01-09 08:35:07          8 days
6       1000 2016-01-15 08:35:07          6 days
7       1000 2016-01-29 08:35:07         14 days
8      10000 2016-01-26 11:57:47          0 days
11     10000 2016-02-02 11:57:47          7 days
12     10000 2016-02-08 11:57:47          6 days
13     10000 2016-02-23 11:57:47         15 days
14    100000 2016-10-13 10:00:01          0 days
17    100000 2016-10-22 10:00:01          9 days
```

Comment: Maybe i did not explain it well,i edited the OP. Anyways thanks for the super quick reply!